# Dummy data generation in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, data-structures, dummy-data

I need some dummy data to a structure such as <64x64 double>. I am able to get <1x64 double> with `1:64` but how to get more dimensions to get `<64x64 double>` in Matlab? I know I can do it like `[1 2 3 4 ... 64; 1 2 3 ...64; ...; 1 2 3 ... 64]` but I am sure there must be some ready command do this fast with arbitrary dummy data. I am also looking for other dummy data generation commands. For example, how can I verify the data structure? Is the supposed way to look for the Workspace window for Name/Value/etc attributes?

Comment: From your recent questions, it looks like you need to sit down with a book on MATLAB before asking questions here. Agreed, SO is a place to learn, but it's not a place to ask first-time-user type of questions...

Comment: @LoremIpsum thank you, generalized it. Now better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a 64x64 all zeros:

```
  a = zeros( 64 );
```

all ones:

```
  a = ones( 64 );
```

random numbers:

```
  a = rand( 64 );
```

1:64^2:

```
  a = reshape( 1 : (64^2), 64, [] );
```

Comment: Thank you +1...is there a command to get increasing numbers? sort(rand(64))? Yes, it worked... :)